# Subtracting groups from two columns based on character string of another column

Tags: r, sorting, subtraction

I have a metadata set where I want to calculate the difference of two numeric columns if they match specific character strings in a different column. For instance, the column `patch` from the `dput()` contains many different IDs: GL134_UP_1, GL24_DN_2, etc where GL# is an ID, UP or DN is a location, and _1, _2, or _3 are replicates. For each individual GL# of a single location and all replicates (GL134_UP_1, GL134_UP_2, GL134_UP_3) I want to subtract numeric values from the column `sn_sp_dist` from the same GL#'s down location (GL134_DN_1, GL134_DN_2, GL134_DN_3).

I imagine I'll be needing `group_by()` to specify the character column, but then I'm lost defining specific GL#'s.

```
library(dplyr)
diff <- met.ex %>%
group_by(patch) %>%


> dput(met.ex)
structure(list(patch = structure(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 
11L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("GL134_DN_1", "GL134_DN_2", "GL134_DN_3", 
"GL134_UP_1", "GL134_UP_2", "GL134_UP_3", "GL22_DN_1", "GL22_DN_2", 
"GL22_DN_3", "GL22_UP_1", "GL22_UP_3"), class = "factor"), sn_sp_dist = structure(c(6L, 
7L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 1L), .Label = c("123", "165", 
"2", "248", "321", "34", "42", "44", "77", "987"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
colnames(met.ex) <- c("patch", "value")

met.ex %>% 
    separate(patch, into = c("id", "direction", "rep"), sep = "_", remove = FALSE) %>%
    # replace all alphabet characters with nothing
    mutate(id = as.numeric(str_match(id, "\\d+")),
        rep = as.numeric(rep),
        patch = as.numeric(patch)) %>%
    select(-patch) %>%
    group_by(id, rep) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = direction, values_from = value) %>%
    mutate(diff = UP - DN)

     id   rep    UP    DN  diff
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   134     1     6     5     1
2   134     2     7     9    -2
3   134     3     2    10    -8
4    22     1     8     3     5
5    22     3     4     1     3
6    22     2    NA     9    NA
```

For more information on cleaning and tidying dataframes read [this](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html#tidy-data-1).

Comment: Hi @Mark thank you for your response.  I've chewed on this for a while but it doesn't work with my "actual" dataset.  Could you please give me your thoughts? > `dput(metadata.ex)
structure(list(patch = c("GL1_DN_1", "GL1_DN_2", "GL1_DN_3", 
"GL1_UP_1", "GL1_UP_2", "GL1_UP_3", "GL10_DN_1", "GL10_DN_2", 
"GL10_DN_3", "GL10_UP_1"), sn_sp_dist..m. = c(2907L, 2907L, 2907L, 
397L, 397L, 397L, 650L, 650L, 650L, 12L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Apologies, I found my mistake: I hadn't changed one instance of `sn_sp_dist` to match the actual metadata. Thank you again

Comment: @Geomicro I just updated it so that it should be a bit more bug-resistant (renamed the columns, used regex)